# redirection while background

Tags: bash, io-redirection, background-process

I wrote some program in Python that printing some message. I want that this program go to background and print its message in a file. So I wrote in bash: `python program > message &`. Problem: the message appears (with cat or vi) only when I interrupt the program. Someone could explain me where is the problem and if there is an easy solution?

Comment: python is using full buffering when its output is not a tty. Try running your program with `python -u` (IIRC)

Comment: According to `python(1)`, the `-u` option will "force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered." @mosvy appears to be correct.

Comment: The standard command stdbuf(1) can be used to ensure any of stdin, stdout, stderr has its buffering mode changed before the program under control inherits the streams. However, there is nothing to prevent that program from switching the stream modes itself again.

Comment: @mosvy Your comment  works perfect ans is my answer! If you write it I validate it.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant `stdbuf` will only work with python2, not with python3 (and not with perl or any program which does NOT use stdio).

Comment: @mosvy I kind of expected that might be so, and noted it. Hard to discover which commands don't use stdio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is using full buffering when its output is not a tty.

Run your program with `python -u` -- which will make the stdout and stderr unbuffered in python3, and also the stdin in python2.

Notice that this has nothing to do with the program running in background, but with the fact that its stdout is not a tty.

Answer (score 0):

Could flush help you here?
I hope linking to other sites is not a problem.
see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function